# Replacing two springs with one equivalent spring and calculating its properties

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image: example, two springs]

Simple question, in a system where a mass is restricted to movement in one dimension (parallel to a) and is suspended as illustrated above by two non-identical springs of differing natural lengths is it possible to replace the system with one equivalent spring fixed at an arbitrary point and if so how would you calculate the properties of this new spring?

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find an equivalent spring. The potential from the two springs will be the sum of two quadratics, which is again a quadratic. The spring constant is basically the coefficient on the square term in the quadratic, so the spring constant of the equilibrium spring will be the sum of the spring constant of the two springs. However, the "natural length" of the equivalent spring is determined by the minimum of the sum of the potentials, and the formula is more complicated than simple addition.